# NGXS version for use selectSnapshot

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

What is the version ngxs/store, angular needs to use this feature? On my version: angular - 5.2, ts - 2.6.2, ngxs/store - 2.1.0-beta.9 i can't use it. 
[In official repo i find this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ0V9.png)

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (3.x) supports Angular/RX 6, if you want support for Angular5, use version 2.x.